# Dynamic image error handling with IE9 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, error-handling

I have some asp.net code which dynamically loads an image control. It works by putting the image into a hidden variable and then setting the url by jquery. It works fine except in IE9 an error always occurs, but I haven't been able to determine what the error is. What property of "err" should I be looking at to get the error, and is there a better way of doing this?

```
<div id="DivFS" class="thumbnailDiv">
    <asp:Image ID="thumbFS" runat="server" CssClass="thumbImage" />
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#thumbFS').error(function (err) {
        });
     $('#thumbFS').attr("src", $('#DocumentFS').val());
    });
</script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="DocumentFS" runat="server" />


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DocumentFS.Value = this.GetUrl(......, UrlType.Thumbnail);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got round this by setting the images to invisible by default and turning their visibility on when they loaded, rather than the other way around (making them visible and then turning them invisible when an error occurred). The error event proved unreliable in IE9, especially when CTRL-F5 was pressed.